# phrase type - Now more than ever

Tags: phrases

I came across the sentence below in a book:

> Now more than ever, leaders need to know how to navigate the rough
>   waters of today's business environment.

I am struggling to figure out what kind of phrase is 'Now more than ever' and need some help.
Clarification: I am not looking for the meaning of the above phrase. I would like to know the type of the phrase itself like absolute phrase, participial phrase and so on. Also some explanation of why it is a particular type would be helpful.

Comment: Your editing changed the question completely.  The three answers below were meant to your original question.

Comment: I had 'phrase type' in the title but probably should have been more clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user3885927 This is actually two phrases. The phrase *now* is a temporal Adjunct (read Adverbial). It's a preposition phrase although in old-fashioned grammars it's often called an adverb when used like this. *More than ever before* is a bit more  difficult. It's an Adjunct, but how to analyse what type of phrase exactly - I'm nor sure, sorry.

Comment: @Centaurus No, I don't think that's fair. None of the answers answered the original question, so the OP helpfully double underlined what the question was about so that it could not be ignored in favour of a question that hadn't been asked. "What kind of phrase is X?" doesn't mean "What does X mean?". It can only be answered like that if you assume the OP doesn't know what they're saying ...

Comment: @Araucaria  The original question was misleading.  So much so that the first three members to answer it didn't understand it for what it was.  If I had read the question after it had been edited, I wouldn't have answered at all.

Comment: @Centaurus Hmm the OQ was: ***phrase type - Now more than ever***

I came across the sentence below in a book:

*"Now more than ever, leaders need to know how to navigate the rough waters of today's business environment"*.
I am struggling to figure out what kind of phrase is '*Now more than ever*' and need some help. <--- It *might* possibly be asking about the meaning, but it doesn't really seem like that if read carefully. Anyhow, you gave a helpful answer for people interested in the meaning ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Now"is an adverb of time in front position followed by an adverbial comparative phrase which means frequency. (According to Michael Swan Practical English Usage )

Comment: Wow! You answered the original question :)

Answer (score 1):

"Now more than ever" puts an emphasis on the present.  In this example, perhaps thousands of years ago, there were no businesses.  In the present, businesses have become increasingly important to society and therefore:

"Now more than ever"   leaders need to learn to navigate the rough waters of a business environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think this must be easier for you: "**At the present time, more than any time in the past**, leaders need to learn  to navigate the rough waters of a business environment."

Comment: Yes, that is a good paraphrase.

Answer (score -1):

> Now more than ever, leaders need to know how to navigate the rough waters.

This could be paraphrased:

*Now (more than ever before) leaders need to know how to navigate the rough waters.*

or this way

*Now leaders need to know how to navigate the rough waters more than they ever did before.*